# How to write xml file to server in php framework codeigniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I want to create the XML and then put it to my server directory i tried the following code but it's work to download the file,

**What i want?**
I want to put that file to my server directory.

```
$data = $this->Xml_model->output_xml_of_listing();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="listingstatus.xml"');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');
echo '<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
        <listing-status>
            <listings>';
            foreach($data as $result) {
                echo '<listing>
                   <listing-key>'.$result["listing_key"].'</listing-key>';
                     if(!empty($result["latitude"]) && !empty($result["longitude"])) {
                     echo '<status>Success</status>
                        <url>'.base_url("property/details")."/".base64_encode($result["listing_id"]).'</url>
                        <message> </message>';
                } else {
                    echo '<status>ERROR</status>
                        <url> </url>
                        <message>Latitude and longitude are missing.</message>';
                }


                echo '<timestamp> </timestamp>
               </listing>';
    }
    echo '</listings>
                </listing-status>
                    </xml>';
```

I also tried `file_put_contents` but it isn't work for me.

Comment: how did you use `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: I assign all the xml to a variable and add the directory path and xml in `file_put_contents()` like this `file_put_contents("rootdirectory/ export.xml", $xml); `

Comment: any error related to it? perhaps you can elaborate..

Comment: no error is showing but the file is not punting in directory

Comment: just a bit curious, you're not on an actual server right? i mean local with pretty much all-you-can-do permissions.. because.. if php did not report any error, it can be something else..

Comment: Hi, Can you explain me about this, am also looking for same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xml is looking good for write use the following code

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/export.xml", $xml);
```

with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` you will get the root directory URL.

Comment: Thanks D.JONE your answer is correct i done this work before your post but happy to see your Answer. thanks so much